# can we buy same product code for buy as gift user in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, purchase-order

My app having a functionality to

1. "buy for self" or
2. user can "gift product" to other user

I have done in-app-purchase functionality for self, But when i am trying to buy product for other user it is not allowed with same apple id.

As per various link

you can gift app --> from app store app --> ...(three dots)--> click ---> there is a option for Gift app
Source: https://www.lifewire.com/gift-an-ipad-app-1994493
----> But my requirement is gift product not app.
[image]

Comment: You can't actually gift IAPs. You can gift *items* that result from IAP. You would use consumable IAPs for this purpose. E.g. your user could purchase 100 "coins" and then transfer some of this balance to another user as a gift, or your user could use those "coins" to purchase a "skin" and then gift that skin to another user; your app is responsible for removing the skin from the purchaser's inventory and transferring it to the recipient's

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 for the update